# configure kafka jdbc source connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am dealing with kafka from a spring boot app
when I produce a message using kafkatemplate and with the use of avro scheme
the produced message is something like:

```
"{\"kkk\":{\"string\":\"somevalue\" ....}
```

but when I use the kafka connect jdbc source connector I am getting something like this:

```
"{\"kkk\":\"somevalue\" ...
```

my question is how to make the jdbc connector produce the same format as the kafkaTemple

Answer (score 0):

The first output shown is Avro JSON encoding. You cannot remove the `string` type unless you make the field a required non-nullable, and non-union type

So, seems the JDBC source has inferred the schema of that column to not have nulls, and the column is always a varchar type.